# SQL data into Stata

Tags: sql, odbc, stata

I'm looking to do some work with pitch level MLB data from here, http://www.baseballheatmaps.com/pitch-fx-download/
It downloads as a single .sql file and I'm having trouble getting it into a usable format. I've figured out it has something to do with the odbc command in Stata, but google searches and forum browsing has not lead me to fully understand how to use it.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Doy have access to a MySQL database that you can load data into?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm not sure what that is. I have access to the network at a major university, 30,000+ students. So if they would have one I could probably use it.

Comment: I am guessing you might have access to one there. Ask your IT people. In that case, you might be able just `odbc sqlfile("pbp2.sql")`.

Answer (score 1):

The "data" within the ZIP archive downloaded from the reference you gave is in reality a SQL program designed to insert data into a SQL database. While the Pitchf/x data is part of the program, it's not in a form that's directly readable by Stata without significant programming (perhaps best done with a tool other than Stata) to disentangle the data from the commands. If you were to find a way to use the program to create and load a SQL-based database, then perhaps Stata's odbc command could be used to read the data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the people who made suggestions - I went with a brute force approach that worked.

The solution I came up with:
I renamed the .sql as .txt - which worked thank goodness. 
In python I printed the first few lines to understand the pattern of the .sql - I found out that each line of data ended with ),

So I replaced ), with ),\n - thus adding in a line break for each observation..

I wrote this into a .txt which I could then read into Stata with insheet.

There's always a way over the wall.